# glob returns an empty list but in debug mode the list returns as intended

Tags: python, list, glob

So, i have the "price.pdf" on my pc. The directory is "D:\python\price.pdf" if i am to be precise.
And here is the code:

```
import glob
pdf_files = glob.glob("*pdf")
print(pdf_files)
```

You can see i have no path, just file format. That's because the .py file and the desired .pdf are in the same directory. I assume i have no need to fill in the path as both files lie together.

The output i get is [] of course.

The tricky part is that the code works fine in debug mode and returns the desired

```
['price.pdf']
```

I tried filling in a path like this

```
pdf_files = glob.glob("D:\\python\*pdf")
```

But it returns this

```
['D:\\python\\price.pdf']
```

I thought maybe there is a conflict between this glob module and some other library, but i am not sure. Any help is welcome. Thanks

Comment: What is "debug mode" here? Running with `python -d program.py`?

Comment: "The directory is "D:\python\price.pdf"": I assume you mean "D:\python", because what you show seems to be a file path, not a directory path.

Comment: What does `print(os.getcwd())` tell you about the current working directory?

Comment: You only mention price.pdf; do you have other PDF files in that directory?

Comment: @Cuteo-P if any one of the answers below helped you, please mark one as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you don't want the full file path in the output, just the filename?
You can remove the parent directory part using pathlib.
This small script lets you define a search directory, finds all pdfs inside, and then just prints the filenames.

```py
from pathlib import Path
# set search directory to any path you like
search_dir = Path("D:\\python")

# find all pdfs in search dir (does not search nested folders, use rglob if desired)
files = search_dir.glob("*.pdf")
#files = search_dir.rglob("*.pdf")

# remove parent from paths
files = [p.name for p in files]

print(files)
```

pathlib contains lots of useful features for working with files, I highly recommend it. https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Answer (score 0):

An `os.path` alternative to @Raphael's answer:

```py
import os, glob

pdf_files = [os.path.basename(i) for i in glob.glob("D:\\python\\*pdf")]

print(pdf_files)
```

Or you can just ensure you are in `D:\python` by explicitly changing the working directory:

```py
import os, glob

os.chdir("D:\\python")

print(glob.glob("*pdf"))
```